# How to test Multiple Conditions before a record is allowed in a Table?

Tags: vba, ms-access, criteria

FOLLOWING ARE OBTAINABLE:

1. There is 1 Session in a Year
2. There are 3 Terms in a Session
3. Student will spend 3 years in the school.
4. A student can only enroll up to 9 different subjects in 1 Term through year 1 to 3.
5. Student will be Promoted to another Class in another Session and offer same subjects. (Require another enrollment, I think)

WHAT I ALREADY HAVE

1. I have a Table called tblEnrolled in which enrollment is recorded.
2. I have a form for the enrollment

I WANT THE FOLLOWING CONDITIONS TO ME MET BEFORE A RECORD IS ALLOWED IN THE TABLE:

1. No student can enroll a perticular Subject more than 1 in a Term (Want to check if the selected Student has already enrolled in the selected Subject for the selected Term and for the selected Session)
2. No student can enroll more than nine (9) different Subjects in a Term.

WHAT I REALLY WANT?

I want the On_Click Event of the SaveButton to check any of the above criteria is not violated.

Thank you for your help.[See the Enrollment Table for a Student, Please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ms32.png)

**EDIT:**
The code only check if a Subject has already been registered for a particular Student.

```
Dim NewSubjectCode As String
Dim NewSubject As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim strMainCriteria As String
On Error GoTo Err

If IsNull(cboSession) Then
    MsgBox "Please select SESSION to proceed.", vbInformation, "Required"
    Me.cboSession.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
If IsNull(cboTerm) Then
    MsgBox "Please select TERM to proceed.", vbInformation, "Required"
    Me.cboTerm.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
If IsNull(cboSelectClass) Then
    MsgBox "Please select CLASS to proceed.", vbInformation, "Required"
    Me.cboSelectClass.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
If IsNull(cboName) Then
    MsgBox "Please select STUDENT to proceed.", vbInformation, "Required"
    Me.cboName.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
If IsNull(cboCode) Then
    MsgBox "Please select SUBJECT to proceed.", vbInformation, "Required"
    Me.cboCode.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

NewSubject = Me.txtSubjects.Value
NewSubjectCode = Me.cboCode.Column(0)
NewStudentID = Me.txtStudentID.Value
stLinkCriteria = "[SubjectCode] = " & "'" & NewSubjectCode & "'"
strCriteria = "[StudentID] = " & "'" & NewStudentID & "'"
strMainCriteria = stLinkCriteria & "And" & strCriteria

If Me.cboCode.Column(0) = DLookup("[SubjectCode]", "QueryEnrollmentDetails", strMainCriteria) Then
    MsgBox "" & NewSubject & " is already selected for this student.", vbCritical, "Duplicate Subject"
    Me.Undo
    Me.cboCode.SetFocus
    Me.txtStudentID = Me.txtID
    Me.txtStudentName = Me.cboName
    Me.txtStudentClass = Me.txtClass
    Me.txtSession = Me.cboSession
    Me.txtTerm = Me.cboTerm
Exit Sub
Else
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Me.[SubformSubjects].Requery
    Me.cboCode.SetFocus
    Me.txtStudentID = Me.txtID
    Me.txtStudentName = Me.cboName
    Me.txtStudentClass = Me.txtClass
    Me.txtSession = Me.cboSession
    Me.txtTerm = Me.cboTerm
End If
Err:
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Thank you so much @David G

Comment: There are several ways you could implement such restrictions/checks. How do you input the data? This determins the way the checks need to be implemented. Do you want to use VBA/SQL/table definitions? If so, did you try anything yet? If so, please post your code/attempts as of now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to use VBA in Access. I use a form to input data into the table.

Comment: So you want some checks in VBA behind your form. Did you do some research? Did you try any code? If so, please post it in your question.

Comment: Thanks again David G. How do I post code here, please? I'm New.

Comment: Edit you question (small "edit" button) and copy-paste your code. Then select your code and use the "code" button at the top ribbon.

Comment: @DavidG thank you so much. I've posted it.

Answer (score 1):

You requirements:

1. No student can enroll a particular Subject more than 1 in a Term (Want to check if the selected Student has already enrolled in the selected Subject for the selected Term and for the selected Session)
2. No student can enroll more than nine (9) different Subjects in a Term.

can be implemented as follows (outline only):

The first can be implemented as the primary key of the table that records who entered for which subject: the combination of Student and Subject is the primary key of that table and a primary key is by definition unique. Trying to insert the combination again will be rejected by the database.

The second can be implement as a `"SELECT Count (*) FROM Subjects WHERE student= " & StudentName & "'"` and then checking the count is less than or equal to 9.

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, I'm not clear about your suggestions.  My point is that, I have a form with couple of combo boxes. I want to check if the combination of my selection on these combo boxes will not result into duplicate record in my table. Hence, I need a VBA code to check before saving the record.  Thanks again

Comment: It will not result in a duplicate entry _if you properly define the Primary Key of your table_! That is the whole idea of Primary Key - look up the concept. The save will fail when attempring to insert a duplicate.

Comment: See for example http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.nl/2008/12/what-is-primary-key.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I later fixed it by using Multiple Criteria to check if such record exits.

The On Click event of the Save Button is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdEnroll_Click()
Dim NewSubjectCode As String
Dim NewSubject As String
Dim strStudent As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strTerm As String
Dim strSession As String
Dim strClass As String
Dim StudentCheck As String
Dim SubjectCheck As String
Dim TermCheck As String
Dim SessionCheck As String
Dim SubjectCodeCheck As String
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim ClassCheck As String
On Error GoTo Err

If IsNull(cboSession) Then
    MsgBox "Please select Session to proceed.", vbExclamation, "Subjects Enrollment"
    Me.cboSession.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
If IsNull(cboTerm) Then
    MsgBox "Please select Term to proceed.", vbExclamation, "Subjects Enrollment"
    Me.cboTerm.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
If IsNull(cboSelectClass) Then
    MsgBox "Please select Class to proceed.", vbExclamation, "Subjects Enrollment"
    Me.cboSelectClass.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
If IsNull(cboName) Then
    MsgBox "Please select Student to proceed.", vbExclamation, "Subjects Enrollment"
    Me.cboName.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
If IsNull(cboCode) Then
    MsgBox "Please select Subject to proceed.", vbExclamation, "Subjects Enrollment"
    Me.cboCode.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

SubjectCheck = Me.txtSubjects.Value
SubjectCodeCheck = Me.cboCode.Column(0)
StudentCheck = Me.txtStudentID.Value
TermCheck = Me.cboTerm.Value
SessionCheck = Me.cboSession.Value
ClassCheck = Me.cboSelectClass.Value
strSubject = "[SubjectCode] = " & "'" & SubjectCodeCheck & "'"
strStudent = "[StudentID] = " & "'" & StudentCheck & "'"
strTerm = "[Term] = " & "'" & TermCheck & "'"
strSession = "[Session] = " & "'" & SessionCheck & "'"
strClass = "[StudentClass] = " & "'" & ClassCheck & "'"

strCriteria = strStudent & "And" & strSubject & "And" & strTerm & "And" & strSession & "And" & strClass

If IsNull(DLookup("[StudentID]", "QueryEnrollmentDetails", strCriteria)) Then

    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblEnrolled(StudentID,StudentName,StudentClass,SubjectCode,SubjectName,Session,Term) " & _
        " VALUES('" & Me.txtID & "','" & Me.cboName & "','" & Me.cboSelectClass & "','" & _
        Me.cboCode & "','" & Me.txtSubjects & "','" & Me.cboSession & "','" & Me.cboTerm & "')"
    Me.[SubformSubjects].Requery
    Me.cboCode.SetFocus
    Me.txtStudentID = Me.txtID
    Me.txtStudentName = Me.cboName
    Me.txtStudentClass = Me.txtClass
    Me.txtSession = Me.cboSession
    Me.txtTerm = Me.cboTerm
Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "" & SubjectCheck & " is already selected for this student.", vbCritical, "Duplicate Subject"
    Me.Undo
    Me.cboCode.SetFocus
    Me.txtStudentID = Me.txtID
    Me.txtStudentName = Me.cboName
    Me.txtStudentClass = Me.txtClass
    Me.txtSession = Me.cboSession
    Me.txtTerm = Me.cboTerm

End If
Exit_Command:
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume Exit_Command
End Sub
```